# AWS ec2 describe-instances without have to use credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to get AWS instance info, local to the instance, without using credentials? I know the command line tool can do it, but it needs credentials. There is also the metadata commands, but those don't seem to return Tags, which is what I need.

I thought there was a way to `curl` an IP and get back json, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** possible to retrieve tags directly from within the EC2 instance via the local metadata service as the metadata service does not know the tags. You have (at least) two options:

1. launch the instance with an IAM role (or somehow provide other credentials to the instance) that includes permission to call ec2:DescribeTags and then retrieve the tags dynamically - you'll need the instance ID for this and you *can* get that from the metadata service
2. if the tags are known at launch time and are **not** going to change after launch, you could simply pass them into the EC2 instance as part of the userdata (e.g. as environment variables or written to a text file at launch).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like we might actually already be set up for this. Looking through our private Git another developer seems to have built this workflow already.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll need credentials to retrieve tags. I do this by creating an IAM user that only has the `ec2:Describe*` role; it can then enumerate the instances in your account and retrieve their tags, with `ec2-describe-tags` or similar.

You can use the metadata API to retrieve the current instance ID, then pass that to ec2-describe tags to retrieve the tags for the current instance:

```
ec2-describe-tags -O YOUR_IAM_KEY -W YOUR_IAM_SECRET --filter="resource-id=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`"
```

Comment: it's not all instances. it's just local one, from within the instance

Comment: instance-metadata doesn't provide tags for the instance. Feel free to demonstrate a POC that says otherwise, but you aren't going to find the Tags that the OP requested in there. My answer stands: you have to use ec2-describe-tags (or equivalent).

Comment: This will work, but it's probably worth noting that it's more typical for the instance to have been launched with an IAM role that includes ec2:DescribeTags than it is to use a dedicated IAM user that only has ec2:Describe*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the EC2 instance tags **without** credentials. You do this using the [EC2 Roles / Profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) for the EC2 instance. I know that this has already been mentioned but I'd like to expand on this a little. Technically you're not actually doing anything without credentials. Credentials are always involved unless you're just making queries to the metadata.

What [Boto](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and other similar frameworks do is they query the ec2 instance metadata to get the credentials for the role. Just replace the last part `s3access` with the name of the profile / role.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access
```

Returns

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2012-04-26T16:39:16Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
  "Token" : "token",
  "Expiration" : "2012-04-27T22:39:16Z"
}
```

This response includes the access credentials required to make the API request. When the credentials expire the framework will request a new set of credentials using the same method and repeat this process as many times as necessary.

I highly recommend using a framework because making the requests directly to the REST API requires that you perform the authentication yourself. If that's the direction you decide to go here are some more resources to help you out.

[Signature Version 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html)

[Describe Tags API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTags.html)